# How to fetch data from open fda API with multiple query parameters using +AND+

Tags: api, openfda

I am using below API query to fetch recalls for food by city AND termination date range.

but it doesn't seem to work

https://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?search=city:%22Westminster%22+AND+termination_date:[2011-01-01+TO+2014-01-01]&limit=3&skip=100

but if I update the query with just (+ : it acts as OR condition) : 
https://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?search=city:%22Westminster%22+termination_date:[2011-01-01+TO+2014-01-01]&limit=3&skip=100

then i get the results.

Seems that the '+AND+' function doesn't respond properly, as there is data already present with the filter I am using with +AND+ query.

Please help.

Comment: I removed `&limit=3&skip=100` from your first query and it returned results... does that mean there are fewer than 100 results?

Comment: It would help if you clarified what you expected to see in the results. Once following @philshem 's pointer and removing the limit, the results are exactly as I'd expect. (That said, it's unfortunate that the "skip" syntax is handled differently when AND is in the query.)

Answer (score 2):

There is only one record in this dataset that matches the criteria you provided, and since you are using the `skip` parameter with a value of `100`, the record essentially gets excluded from the result set. Try dropping the `skip` parameter: [https://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?search=city:"Westminster"+AND+termination_date:[2011-01-01+TO+2014-01-01]&limit=3](https://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?search=city:%22Westminster%22%20AND%20termination_date:[2011-01-01%20TO%202014-01-01]&limit=3)